Weird CMD process takes up 30% CPU Usage
I need some help over here.
I have lately noticed that if I look on my CPU usage in NZXT Cam there is a process that's just called "cmd" that use about 30% of my CPU even in idle.
As soon as I open up task manager the process quickly drop utilization and drops down the list of NZXT Cam so that I cannot end it. Trough some detective-work with installing btop to the command line that luckily don't triggers the hiding of the process I can get its PID and then through task manager end it and it disappears for that boot but as soon as I reboot it's right there again.
No matter where I look I can't seem to find what command it's actually running and then get what is causing it. I even went so far to follow a guide on how to track all CMD processes from boot and looking through them all in Event Viewer but as far as I can google myself to all of them seems legit.
Have anyone else seen this before or have any tips on how to fix it. I'm guessing can be solved by reinstalling Windows but I rather not do that.
I have attached some images on it here though it doesn't say much:




Have you tried Process Explorer? It can show a process's command line and its parent process.

In Task Manager, you can right-click a process and then select “Open file location”. Where is this fake cmd.exe located? // Either way, the only way to make (reasonably) sure a system is no longer compromised is clear: Nuke it, then reinstall.

You can right click on the column header row and select show command line to get more information

Install WinDBG using the method of your choice. On the launch screen, you should be able to attach it to a running process, by using the search bar to filter for "cmd" processes or by directly searching for the PID (from your screenshot it seems to be 29108, but this number will change). WinDBG does not show usage values, but it does show the command that spawned the process. Take a look at the screenshot below for reference.
WinDBG Startup Screen

Breaking site rules is not helpful. However, this is enough of an answer that your comment about not being able to comment is unnecessary. Please keep in mind going forward that if you cannot comment and you only have a comment to add, do not use that as an excuse to post that comment as an answer. Rather, use it to motivate you to earn the reputation necessary so that you CAN comment.

Thanks! i tried that but as soon as I attached the process it seems like it crashes and disappears for good. I can't really see what commands it runs or where it comes from
